# Is there a way to console log whenever a component is rendered or re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a suspicion that my React app is re-rendering a lot of components due to some unknown errors in my code. I want to be made aware each time any of my components re-render.

I can go into each component and add a console log at the top of each render method but that would be time consuming since there are a lot of components and I would have to do this each time I add a new one.

Is there any "catch all middle-ware" that can be run right before any React component is about to render/re-render? One that sit's globally in one place and works for all components across the board?

Comment: This document can lead you onto the right path. https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html

Comment: You can use the chrome react extension and click "highlight updates"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any "catch all middle-ware" that can be run right before any
>   React component is about to render/re-render? One that sit's globally
>   in one place and works for all components across the board?

I know about one. [why-did-you-update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update).

Answer (score 3):

why-did-you-update is deprecated, here is the latest lib:
[@welldone-software/why-did-you-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render)